# How to code a js that would replace the text inside a tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, toggle

How to code a js that would replace the text inside a tag?
I have a dropdown mobile menu using this javascript:

```
toggle.js

$(function ()
{
var $window = $(window),
    $nav = $('nav'),
    $button = $('button');

$button.on('click', function ()
{
    $nav.slideToggle();
});

$window.on('resize', function ()
{
    if ($window.width() > 320)
    {
        $nav.show();
    }
});
});

Here is the section of HTML
<button>Select Destinations
<img src="images/down-arrow.png" width="20" height="20"/>
</button>
<nav id="menu">     
<a href="#">Philadelphia</a>
<a href="#">United States of America</a>
<a href="#">Philippines</a>
<a href="#">Long Destinations Names</a>
<a href="#">Some Destination</a>
<a href="#">Australia</a>
</nav>
```

I need "Select Destinations" to be replaced by whatever the selected button from the dropdown. ex. If i select "Los Angeles", it should replace "Select destinations" to " Los Angeles". I tried dropdown list but it looks different from differenct devices.

can anyone share some info? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without touching anything of your HTML

```
img_arrow = '<img src="images/down-arrow.png" width="20" height="20"/>';

$('#menu a').click(function(e){

    $('button').html($(this).html() + img_arrow);

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adriantombu/LDfLf/)

Comment: thanks Adrian, so i came up with this to add the drop down.:

http://jsfiddle.net/cyberjo50/4vZbU/

i added it to your code.

Comment: by the way it works in JsFiddle but it didn't work when i added it to my code in dreamweaver. do i need to download the jQuery2.0?

Comment: I'm using this:
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: It works fine even with jQuery 1.6.4 (you can change the version on jsFiddle), so I guess it's something else in your HTML who messes with this. Do you have other '#menu a' or 'button' element on your page ?

Comment: here is the page im working on:
http://t4fresponsivelandingpage.businesscatalyst.com/lp_templ.html

Comment: the word "Select Destination" won't change if any buttons is selected. you should view it in 525width to view the problem

Answer (score 1):

In JQuery, text found inside a tag is accessed via:

```
$(obj).text();
```

or

```
$(obj).html();
```

Call them without any arguments and it retrieves the current values, pass in your own string and it replaces what it has inside.

Comment: $(function ()
    {
    var $window = $(window),
        $nav = $('nav'),
        $button = $('button');

    $button.on('click', function ()
    {
        $nav.slideToggle();
  $(obj).button('test');
    });

    $window.on('resize', function ()
    {
        if ($window.width() > 320)
        {
            $nav.show();
        }
    });
    });

Comment: sorry, I should have clarified, don't actually use $(obj), i was just using it as an example... you would probably use $button.text('test') or something similar.  If you are inside your $button.on('click'.. function then you can just use $(this).text('test')

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery, you can replace the element within a tag by:

```
$('.myselector').html('stuff to put inside my selector');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
//Javascript
$("nav#menu a").click(function()
{
    $("span").text($(this).text());
});

// HTML
Here is the section of HTML
<button><span>Select Destinations</span>
<img src="images/down-arrow.png" width="20" height="20"/>
</button>
<nav id="menu">     
<a href="#">Philadelphia</a>
<a href="#">United States of America</a>
<a href="#">Philippines</a>
<a href="#">Long Destinations Names</a>
<a href="#">Some Destination</a>
<a href="#">Australia</a>
</nav>
```